# mongo-hadoop - saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile() - old folders not being cleaned up

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

## DESCRIPTION

Our application is using mongo-hadoop saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile() method to write into Mongo. It works well for days, but at some point, it reaches the item/name quota limit of the HDFS folder used as temporary output buffer. That causes an "Could not open temporary file for buffering Mongo output" exception in the [MongoRecordWriter](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/8f2699af4272e4de89f5925937937c85b0e031d9/core/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/output/MongoRecordWriter.java) class (see stack trace below) and prevents any further writing into MongoDB from the application.

After doing some digging, we noticed that the *cleanupResources(final TaskAttemptContext taskContext)* method of the [MongoOutputCommitter](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/mongodb/hadoop/output/MongoOutputCommitter.java#L225) class in mongo-hadoop deletes temporary files created for the output task, but not the folder containing each temp file. We haven't found any setting/config option to control that behaviour. We can increase the name quota for that HDFS folder, but that's likely to have a performance impact in HDFS and it doesn't solve anything. We can have a nohup maintenance job, but that's an additional artefact to manage and we see it as a workaround.

## QUESTIONS

1. Is there any way to control that behaviour via configuration?
2. If not, can this be considered a feature or a bug? Perhaps it was
       left to the HDFS administrator to manage old temporary empty
       folders, although I'm not sure about that.

## STACK TRACE

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not open temporary file for buffering Mongo output
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.MongoOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(MongoOutputFormat.java:46)
...
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.FSLimitException$MaxDirectoryItemsExceededException): The directory item limit of /user/ec2-user/tmp is exceeded: limit=1048576 items=1048576
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.verifyMaxDirItems(FSDirectory.java:2021)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.addChild(FSDirectory.java:2072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.unprotectedMkdir(FSDirectory.java:1841)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsRecursively(FSNamesystem.java:4348)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInternal(FSNamesystem.java:2748)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFileInt(FSNamesystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.startFile(FSNamesystem.java:2519)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.create(NameNodeRpcServer.java:566)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:394)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:962)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2039)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2035)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1635)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2033)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1402)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.create(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:295)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor27.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.newStreamForCreate(DFSOutputStream.java:1725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.create(DFSClient.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$6.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.create(DistributedFileSystem.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:895)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:792)
    at com.mongodb.hadoop.output.MongoRecordWriter.<init>(MongoRecordWriter.java:75)
    ... 9 more
```

Comment: I've reported to Mongo-hadoop team [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-292) as a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It was reported as a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-292). And it was fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/commit/6b16268ed881f42aeee6d69c23bdeb5f1a0c399f) in r2.0.0-rc0.

Answer (score 0):

I have also met this exception, but the version I used is 2.0.2. It may not be fixed yet.